# How can I send 1.25 billion IDR from Saudi Arabia to Indonesia

Tags: international-transfer, saudi-arabia

I am a Saudi citizen, my wife is Indonesian and I am buying a house in Jakarta. I am having hard time finding a way to transfer the money (1.25 billion IDR), roughly ($100k USD) to Indonesia. It seems that there's a limit on most services (25k-30k SAR) either a monthly limit (such as western union, moneygram), or a per transaction limit (5k for moneygram).

I just need to transfer the money at once to our bank account in Indonesia. How can I do that legally and without any hassles?

Comment: If you are talking about that much money, you would be foolish not to hire a professional to advise you. The internet is not an adequate substitute.

Answer (score 2):

I just called the customer service of a real bank, not a money transfer service. It seems that the limit is on the electronic transactions only. If you show up at the bank the limits tend to be huge or do not exist (the bank rep. just told me that he is not aware of a limit in this specific bank).

Comment: Actually, there are two huge companies ofx.com and transferwise that exist for this very puirpose, Pani.  It's possible the rates will be a bit better with them.  (I'm not sure if they operate in Saud, you should check before doing the transfer!  You could save money.